# Enterprise Search Crawl Log - How long are deleted items recorded?

Tags: 2013, enterprise-search, crawling

I'm just looking for a quick explanation of the "Deleted" index items in the crawl log of 2013 ES. It seems the number tallies all the items deleted for the past several months but I can't find any documentation on exactly how far back it goes. We're trying to track the size reduction of a content source over time but without some sort of context on the "Deletes" number I can't do that beyond an educated guess.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know what is default retention period of the crawl logs. But using the [SearchServiceApplication.CrawlLogCleanupIntervalInDays](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.search.administration.searchserviceapplication.crawllogcleanupintervalindays.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) you can set it to as per your requirement. this method have both get and sets, which may help you to get existing cleanup.

http://sharepoint-community.net/profiles/blogs/large-msscrawlurllog

> When a crawler cannot find an item that exists in the index because
>   the URL is obsolete or it cannot be accessed due to a network outage,
>   the crawler reports an error for that item in that crawl. If this
>   continues during the next three crawls, the item is deleted from the
>   index.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff621096%28v=office.14%29.aspx